# Use a static IP for NAT instead of DHCP

Tags: ubuntu, ip

I have a virtual Ubuntu running and I want it to share my IP, ie use NAT.But I don't want to use DHCP,

I will be testing some client/server apps from my native os to my virtual. I want the apps to point to the static IP of my virtual machine.

I have gotten and used vmnetcfg.exe but I can only seem to adjust the DHCP range and lease settings for nat, I don't see a way of setting it to a static IP.

Does anybody know a way to do this?

If I am wrong and I shouldn't be using static IPs for nat and I should use host-only or something can someone tell me how?(Because I have tried host-only and set my VM to a static Ip with no luck also).

Any help would be great,

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just tell the guest OSs to use a static address in the range of addresses the NAT server would have given out.  NAT does not require the clients to use DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC VMWare only hands out the back half of the range (*.*.*.128-255) as DHCP addresses, so you can use the front half, less the control addresses, (so *.*.*.3-127) for static addresses - just give you Ubuntu VM an address in that range.